# Implementing CreateEvent() , SetEvent() and waitForMultipleobject() In Linux

Tags: c++, linux

Hi I am porting my application from windows to Linux and have few common window's functions like CreateEvent and SetEvent and waitForMultipleobject.

For CreateEvent and SetEvent I have implemented functions using semaphores.
Example CreateEvent -> sem_init;
SetEvent -> sem_post;

For WaitforMultipleobjects I have used epoll in Linux.

The parameters passed to below functions are wrt to my application.

Here is the code:

```
#include <sys/epoll.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <semaphore.h>

sem_t FEvent1 ;
int value;
int event_count;
int running =1;

int EpollCreate(int flags=0)
{
   int epoll_fd = epoll_create1(flags);
   printf("instance of epoll cretaed %d\n ",epoll_fd );
 
  if(epoll_fd == -1)
  {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create epoll file descriptor\n");
    return 1;
  }
 
    return epoll_fd;
}

void Epoll_control(int epoll_fd,int fd)
{

  struct epoll_event event;
    event.events = EPOLLIN;
     event.data.fd = fd;

  if(epoll_ctl(epoll_fd, EPOLL_CTL_ADD,fd, &event))
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Failed to add file descriptor to epoll\n");
      close(epoll_fd);
      return;
  }
  
}

int Epoll_Wait(int epoll_fd, int maxevents, int timeout)
{
  struct epoll_event *events = new struct epoll_event[maxevents]; 
  int event_count = epoll_wait(epoll_fd, events, maxevents, timeout);
  printf("Event count is :: %d\n",event_count);
  delete[] events;
  return event_count;
}

int main(){


sem_init(&FEvent1, 0, 1);                             // For CreateEvent()
sem_getvalue(&FEvent1,&value);
printf("The initial value of the semaphore is %d\n", value);

sem_post(&FEvent1);                                 //For SetEvent()
sem_getvalue(&FEvent1, &value);
printf("The value of the semaphore after the post is %d\n", value);

int epoll_fd = EpollCreate(0);
Epoll_control(epoll_fd,value);

printf("\nPolling for input...\n");
event_count = Epoll_Wait(epoll_fd,5,3000);
printf("%d ready events\n", event_count);
  
}
```

Here is the output :

```
    The initial value of the semaphore is 1
    The value of the semaphore after the post is 2
    instance of epoll cretaed 3
     
    Polling for input...
    Event count is :: 0
    0 ready events
```

So in the output the issue can be make out like the event count is 0 which means no event is signaled.
I am using epoll as in my windows application waitForMultipleObjects is waiting for number of events and all are of type Integer.
so any idea how to resolve the above issue? like how to make the event fd signaled?
Moreover FEvent1 is of type sem_t , which cannot be passed to epoll_ctl and for that reason used sem_getvalue().
Any help on this is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Got the solution using eventfd() instead of semaphores.